# After a successful Magento payment via SagePay, the customer is redirected to the empty basket page. Why?

Tags: magento, opayo

As a team we're currently investigating a strange occurrence. It doesn't seem to apply to all orders by any means, but it is affecting a large number of customers based on the logging we've added to the `noItems.phtml` page.

***Please note:** I'm not really expecting an answer as I assume this is a problem we have to solve ourselves based on addons, and our server configuration (three servers for loading balancing). However, I am looking for possible ideas and/or whether this is something somebody has come across previously.*

What we've done so far, and what we know:

- User enters their card details in the SagePay iFrame;
- User purchases an item via SagePay -- order is successful;
- **Some** users are sent back to the success page;
- **Some** users don't see the success page (phoned to confirm a handful) but instead return back to the empty basket;

We're still investigating, but we find it ever so strange how a user would return to the empty basket page. We've added logging to the `noItems.phtml` and we can see that *some* users are getting assigned another session ID after a successful transaction. This seems to be the problem, but why the user is being assigned another session ID after a SagePay payment isn't easy to comprehend.

Has anybody else experienced a similar issue with SagePay/Magento? And if so, what steps did you take to solve?

Comment: There's no noticeable pattern relating to the card types used for the failed session redirect? I remember there was an old issue with Amex in server-server mode -  http://jamesallen.name/index.cfm/2009/5/19/SagePay-Inconsistency-in-IFrame-Low-profile-option-on-Server-solution-workaround

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But there doesn't seem to be any consistency in the types of cards that see this problem. Also the majority of our customers use Visa/Mastercard who typically have to enter the code.

Answer (score 2):

Our Sage Pay Support team would be happy to look at the transaction logs (within 72 hours of the transation being submitted) and help you determine the reason for the failed transactions on 0845 111 4455 24/7.

You reply to the Notification URL when you acknowledge receipt of our response. You have 20 seconds to response. You need to send the Status (OK, Error or Invalid), Status Detail and Redirect URL. We then send the shopper back to your Redirect URL.

A few suggestions would be:

If we can't reach your Notification URL, check you have ports 443 and 80 open. Check you don't have a DNS issue.

If you are receiving the notification from Sage Pay to confirm the status of the transaction via the Notification URL. Check the information you are sending is in the correct casing, that it is not empty data and that your website is not spooling and check whether the success/failure URL is a valid landing page.

All our system needs is the Status Deatil, 'Status = ' and 'RedirectURL =' fields with the appropriate values assigned, separated with Carriage-Return and Line-Feeds (as specified in the protocol) . Nothing else is required. The response you send should also be text/plain message, not text/html or any other MIME type.

If the customer is being sent back to an empty basket, check whether your website is doing a job in the background such as writing to a databse, preparing confirmation emails to the back office before sending the customer to the payment page.  Test whether your server can handle the amount of transactions coming through from Sage Pay. Or are you truncating the NEXT URL?

Regarding a session ID, each transaction is assigned a unique Sage Pay ID called a VPSTxID which is used to identify the transaction. We can take a look at the transactions you are referring to if you are getting several session IDs to discuss further if you would like.

Sage Pay Support.

Answer (score 0):

Check the action that pushes the user to the success page on successful purchase. Maybe its something like target _parent. Maybe its something where its trying to load the success page in the iframe. Or maybe its timing out on sagepay when trying to redirect.